# Can jgroups inform us about node status (especially when node goes out)

Tags: jboss, cluster-computing, jgroups

I have a question about how does jgroups ***re-enter node*** (that goes out from) in cluster again, i.e this node is disconnect because of network off and then re-join when network is on again.

1. Haw does Jgroups handle this task (return to the Cluster Nodes) ?
2. Is there a way to inform us about this behvior ( when a node goes out from cluster) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A node that leaves (gracefully) or crashes, is removed from the cluster and a new view without that node is installed. So, for example, if we have view v1={A,B,C,D}, and D crashes, a new view v2={A,B,C} will be installed.
The view change can be received as callback by overriding viewChanged(), e.g.

```
JChannel ch;
ch.setReceiver(this);
...

public viewChanged(View v) {
     // handle the view change
}
```

If D didn't crash, but someone pulled the ethernet cable, D will get removed as well. When the cable is reinserted later, a so called MergeView v3={A,B,C,D} will be installed.
Merging is done via the MERGE3 protocol; failure detection via FD_SOCK/FD_ALL/FD.

I recommend the JGroups manual for details.
Cheers,

Comment: thx for these clarifications, 
For the second part can you tell me if there is any way that i can be informed about a node that goes out from cluster ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, viewChange() is called whenever a new node join, or an existing node leaves